# Tubeless tires and compatibility

Tags: road-bike, tire, wheels, compatibility, tubeless

Can 25mm tubeless tires fit on a wheel that previously had 22mm tubeless tires? I have a set of wheels that previously had 22mm tires on it. There is no description of tire compatibility listed on the wheels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rim width / tire section tolerance?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/rim-width-tire-section-tolerance) and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle

Comment: Provided the frame and the brake calipers have the clearance it is unlikely to be the problems but you should betr tell as the size of the rim and not the old tyre.

Answer (score 0):

Generally road tubeless is road tubeless and going to the 25 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend tracking down the rim manufacturer's recommendations. Standards for road tubeless are still not completely settled, and [manufacturer don't even agree on what makes for a safe setup](https://www.velonews.com/gear/tech-faq-hooked-vs-hookless-rims-tire-choice-and-pressure-recommendations/). Tolerances are tighter than with tubed setups, and [as this case suggests](https://www.velonews.com/gear/technical-faq-specialized-turbo-2bliss-tire-blowoff/), putting on a tire that is a fraction of a millimeter too wide may result in a blowoff, which can be catastrophic.

That said, a 25-mm tire is not very wide. It's hard to imagine any rim manufacturer building a road rim these days that would be incompatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any consolation; my road and gravel bike share the same wheelsets. All four sets are set up tubeless, have an inner width of 24mm, and I have mounted many dozens of tires on them. Sizes ranging from 700 x 23 up to 29 x 1.8" and everything in-between. No burps, no blown out beads, no problems other than changing out sealant, and re-taping the rim beds about every 2 years.

Comment: I would guess the OPs rims wil be much thinner.

Comment: Perhaps, but along the same vein; I’m currently running a set of 2.3” MTB tires on a 19mm internal width rim.