# How to find out the inner rim width

Tags: rims

I own a Marin Presidio 2 and I have checked every single page of theirs and all of the information I can find is that the rim is "Marin Aluminum Double Wall, Disc Specific".

I've inspected the rim and tried to find anything written on it for information, but I see nothing. The only solution would be to pull out the tire and measure it myself, but I'm wondering if there is any other way aside from that to figure out the inner width of my rim.

Comment: Why are you wanting to know? If it's because you're thinking about getting different tires, [you have a lot of wiggle room](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/rim-width-tire-section-tolerance?rq=1).

Comment: Marin is the kind of brand that I would wager to be pretty responsive to emails with questions such as this

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know about your specific rim, but usually the inner width is around 4mm less than the outer width.

But as jimchristie points out in the comments, usually there is a very wide range of tyre widths you can install on a given rim. On a typical 19mm inner width trekking bike rim you can install pretty much anything from <s>28mm</s> 23mm to 50mm (assuming your frame and fork have enough clearance).

Comment: Are you going by the old ISO standards for what’s safe? They’re conservative. You could mount tires as narrow as 23mm if you wanted for whatever reason.

Comment: Good point, let me lower that number. I think the maximum width is also relatively conservative. I’ve used 35mm tyres on 13mm inner width rims.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the rim inner width and can't find any written specifications you are stuck with measuring the rim you have.

[image]
[Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rim-sizing.html)

Comment: Calipers (vernier, digital) are an ideal tool for this purpose, or a good hard-ended ruler plus lots of light can be sufficient.  A number accurate to a millimetre is good enough.